# Get specific words from Word to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have Word documents that contain certain serial numbers (all of them begin with either 3BMS*, or 7SGA*) that I need to extract into Excel. Each Word document contains hundreds of serial numbers.

The method I am trying is that the VBA opens up the Word document and uses search to find the words that contain the first four digits of the serial number. I would then run the code for each of the two codes.

I have VBA to find paragraphs that contains the search word.

```
While oRange.Find.Execute = True

    oRange.Select
            
    myPara = oDoc.Range(0, oWord.Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.End).Paragraphs.Count

    CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1

    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 1) = oDoc.Paragraphs(myPara).Range

    oRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

Wend
```

How do I return only the word containing the search result, not the whole paragraph?

Comment: Maybe using `Regexp`? For example [this](https://regex101.com/r/y0Jg6O/1)

Answer (score 0):

With your previous code in mind, something like the following should work. This will search the document for each instance of 3BMS plus the alphanumeric values directly after it and insert that value into the referenced cell. It will then do the same for 7SGA*.

```
' Search the document for the first serial number type
Set oRange = oDoc.Content
Do While oRange.Find.Execute("3BMS[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}", MatchWildcards:=True)
    CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1
    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 1) = oRange.Text
Loop

' Search the document for the second serial number type
Set oRange = oDoc.Content
Do While oRange.Find.Execute("7SGA[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}", MatchWildcards:=True)
    CurrRowShtExtract = CurrRowShtExtract + 1
    shtExtract.Cells(CurrRowShtExtract, 1) = oRange.Text
Loop
```